# Getting all registered users from Django's inbuilt user model into a class within admin.py

Tags: django, class, admin

I am fairly new to Django and can just about articulate what I am trying to do, so I apologise if the title isn't accurate.

I am using this survey app - https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey

Within admin.py, I have the following two classes:

```
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'is_published', 'need_logged_user', 'template')
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'need_logged_user')
    inlines = [CategoryInline, QuestionInline]
    actions = [make_published]

class ResponseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('interview_uuid', 'survey', 'created', 'user')
    list_filter = ('survey', 'created')
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    inlines = [
        AnswerTextInline, AnswerRadioInline, AnswerSelectInline,
        AnswerSelectMultipleInline, AnswerIntegerInline
    ]
    # specifies the order as well as which fields to act on
    readonly_fields = (
        'survey', 'created', 'updated', 'interview_uuid', 'user'
    )
```

These create the pages for "Responses" and "Surveys" in the Admin page.

[Admin area with Response and Survey links / their outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M74I5.png)

I can list the usernames of each user that submitted a Response to the Survey (using TabularInLine and model.response), but what I want to do is list all of the users that exist (so that I can add a timestamp of when they submitted their Response to the Survey/Filter by Response date/etc.).

What I've tried since is importing User from contrib.auth.models and creating a new UserAdmin class (so that I can at least list all users, and move on from there).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
admin.site.unregister(User)
...
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username',)
...
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I don't get any errors, but it's not displaying the UserAdmin class in the Admin page.

How can I list **all** of the registered users into the Admin page (in order to later add the timestamp of when a Response was submitted, *if* one was submitted)?

I'm using Django 1.11 if that's relevant.

Comment: Django admin already provides users to be displayed. but i guess you are looking for a way to add timestamp when a response has been submitted by the user. right ?

Comment: That's correct. I don't mind adding it to the already provided users, if that's possible, but thought it better to add under the Surveys section

Comment: I aim to have multiple surveys, so I envisioned it as a Surveys page that lists all the surveys, and with inlines, list ALL users, and a timestampe for when they completed the survey.... But I don't know how to access/pull in the users from djangos provided user model.

Comment: you want to do this in admin only or at the front end part in templates?

Comment: I read through the documentation and some of the questions/answers on stackoverflow last night and this morning. I _think_ (please tell me if I am wrong) what I should be doing is using a query_set in the template to get all users, and filter this by users who have submitted a response. If there's a way to do it in the admin, I would be really interested in this as I think a dashboard of all users would look better for this app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a list of all the user in the admin with the code you gave. Maybe you don't have any users in database ? I can't see the exact problem right now.

But without modifying the app, you should be able to see when a "Response" has been submitted or updated with the `created` or `updated` attribute of the [Response class](https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey/blob/3cd2b593ec2eba09819153c4170eb3ae69c38a55/survey/models/response.py#L35) :

For example if you want to list the user and date of submission of a survey contained in the `survey` variable:

```
for response in survey.reponses:
    print(response.user, "answered at", response.created)
```

If you want to loop on all users and see if the survey has been answered:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    response = Reponse.objects.filter(survey=survey, user=user)
    if response:
         print(user, "answered at", response.created)
    else:
         print(user, "never answered")
```

I hope this help.